# Формирование curl запроса при помощи HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, curl, bitcoin, rpc

Пытаюсь сделать запрос при помощи HttpURLConnection на локально установленную ноду работающую через RPC. Как можно преобразовать запрос curl ?:

```
    curl http://login:password@127.0.0.1:18443/ 
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
    -d '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "method": "nameMethod" , "params": []}'
```

Если конкретнее проблема заключается в авторизации пользователя:

```
    http://login:password@127.0.0.1:18443/
```

если задать такой URL в HttpURLConnection to выдаст 401 - Unauthorized.

Пробовал добавить

```
    con.setRequestProperty ("Authorization","login:password");
```

И все подобное что нашел в гугле, но все безрезультатно. Однако запрос curl представленный в начале успешно выдает результат если использовать в консоли. 
Так же в консоли успешно срабатывает такой запрос (с добавлением --user):

```
    curl http://127.0.0.1:18443 
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
    --user "merenion:841007" 
    -d '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "method": "nameMethod", "params": []}'
```

Попробовал добавить basic  аутентификацию - выдало 500. Код:

```
public static String execute() {
    try {
        String url ="http://127.0.0.1:18443/";
        URL object = new URL(url);

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("username:password").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);


        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.write("{\"jsonrpc\": \"1.0\", \"method\": \"getblockchaininfo\", \"params\": [] }");

        //вывод
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int HttpResult = con.getResponseCode();
        if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            br.close();
            return sb.toString();
        } else {
            return con.getResponseMessage();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        log.error("Не корректный URL" ,e);
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        log.error("Ошибка выполнения....",e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Ошибка выполнения запроса",e);
    }
    return "error";
}
```

Comment: Вам нужна Basic аутентификация, посмотрите реализацию в этом вопросе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019997/preemptive-basic-auth-with-httpurlconnection

Comment: Добавил в описание проблемы результат

Comment: Пробовали посмотреть в отладчике хрома, например, что происходит на данном сайте при авторизации? На какую страницу и какой запрос отправляется. Возможно достаточно просто в параметрах прописать user и password, а не устанавливать заголовки.

Comment: Это не сайт) это нода которая запущена локально и работает через rpc, экспериментирую с ней для дальнейшего использования..